# Include fonts in open-source project

Tags: open-source

If I want to include a font in my open-source project, how do I know if its OK to do this?

Are the fonts that come with MS Windows ok?

Are the fonts that come with OSX ok?

Are the fonts that come with Linux ok?

Are the Google open fonts ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are sources for free fonts, but none of the fonts you mention are *necessarily* going to be among them, although the Google Web Fonts are probably your best bet.

It's just like any code that you're planning to incorporate into your project: if you didn't write it, find out what the license says. What you want are fonts that are not just "free", or "open source" but free to **redistribute**. [Here's a relevant discussion on gamedev.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/360/where-can-i-find-fonts-which-i-can-distribute-with-an-open-source-game)

[Here's a list](http://osliving.com/sourced/open-source-fonts/web-resources/) of five sources for open source fonts, many of which will fit your criteria. (It includes Google Web Fonts.)

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to use mine: http://www.dafont.com/nadall.font :)

Comment: Nice font! (In this case my designer had a sans-serif type font in mind - we're sprucing up the sample app in www.typhoonframework.org )